# Query not sending

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am attempting to create a second prepared statement after one I already had in place. I am getting an error saying the number of variables do not match up. I think it is saying that because of the 'date_requested' in the prepare section. I have done this in another queries and it did not throw an error for it. I am not sure if this is what is causing the code to break or what, but this is not sending anything of the second query through. The first is still sending fine.

Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home4/pfarley1/public_html/sundayfundayleague.com/register.php on line 137

Line 137 is

```
    $stmt->bind_param('iisssssi', $id, $user_id, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $username, $status, $group);
```

This is the code for two of my queries on the page. The first one works perfect, but with the second one I am getting that error.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $id = ( isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ? $_SESSION['id'] : "" );
   $user_id = ( isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ? $_SESSION['id'] : "" );
   $firstname = Input::get('firstname');
   $payment_name = "Owes";
   $payment_id = 1;
   $payment_amount = 0;

//Query to add user's name to owes db table

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
/* check connection */
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO payment_status 
        (id, user_id, firstname, payment_name, payment_id, payment_amount) 
        VALUES 
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    if ( false===$stmt ) {
  // Check Errors for prepare
  die(' Owes DB prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
}
$stmt->bind_param('iissii', $id, $user_id, 
                 $firstname, $payment_name, 
                 $payment_id, $payment_amount);
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
      // Check errors for binding parameters
      die('Owes DB bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
$stmt->execute();

    if ( false===$stmt ) {
      die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }   
}

//Query that adds user to User Request db table

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $id = ( isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ? $_SESSION['id'] : "" );
        $user_id = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );
        $firstname = Input::get('firstname');
        $lastname = Input::get('lastname');
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $username = Input::get('username');
        $status = "Pending";
        $group = 1;


        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
    /* check connection */
       if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
        $stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_requests 
        (id, user_id, firstname, lastname, email, username, status, `group`, date_requested) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
            if ( false===$stmt2 ) {
          // Check Errors for prepare
          die('User Request prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
            }
        $stmt->bind_param('iisssssi', $id, 
       $user_id, $firstname, $lastname, $email, 
       $username, $status, $group);
            if ( false===$stmt2 ) {
              // Check errors for binding parameters
              die('User Request bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
            }
        $stmt->execute();
            if ( false===$stmt2 ) {
              die('User Request execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
            }
    }
```

Does any one see what I'm doing wrong?

Like this?...

```
    if (!$stmt2->bind_param('iisssssi', $id, $user_id, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $username, $status, $group) {
    die('User Request bind_param() failed...);
          // Check errors for binding parameters
          die('User Request bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
        }
```

Comment: It's a typo or copy/paste error. In your second statement, you use the variable `$stmt2`, but you call `bind_param()` on `$stmt->bind_param(), $stmt->execute()`. Everything else looks correct.

Comment: Note that checking `if(false === $stmt2)` after the `bind_param(),execute()` calls is not going to work as intended. In those cases, the object in `$stmt2` will never be set to false, but the method calls will _return_ false.  Instead, check it as `if (!$stmt->bind_param(...)) { die('User Request bind_param() failed...);`  Same goes for `execute()`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I cannot believe I missed that. I updated my question with what you suggested...at the bottom. Is that how I would structure it?

Comment: Yes that is the exact idea, but I think you missed a closing `)` for the `if (`.  `bind_param()` and `execute()` both return `false`, but neither has the ability to modify the variable `$stmt2` to make it `false`. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php